# PHP round($num,2) and javascript toFixed(2) is not giving right output for this value 53.955

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, php-5.6

I have one php function and having

`phpans  = round(53.955,2)`

and javascript function

```js
var num  = 53.955;
var jsans = num.toFixed(2);
console.log(jsans);
```

both jsans and phpans is giving different **$phpans** = **53.96** ans **jsans** = **53.95** . I can not understand why this is happening ..
Thanks is Advance

Comment: Thanks @Edwin for In-proving my answer

Comment: I have created a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803587/why-tofixed-in-javascript-acts-like-that.

Comment: Hello @Edwin Thanks for creating This question I also wanted to know why toFixed() have this weired answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because computers can't represent floating numbers properly. It's probably 53.95400000000009 or something like that. The way to deal with this is multiply by 100, round, then divide by 100 so the computer is only dealing with whole numbers.

```js
var start = 53.955,
        res1,
        res2;
    
    res1 = start.toFixed(2);
    res2 = (start * 100).toFixed(0) / 100;
    console.log(res1, res2);
```

```
//Outputs
"53.95"
53.96
```

Answer (score 0):

**JAvascript toFixed:**
The toFixed() method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

**php round:**
Returns the rounded value of val to specified precision (number of digits after the decimal point). precision can also be negative or zero (default).

Conclusion tofixed not working like php round. **precision** Specifies the number of decimal digits to round to.

**Javascript function :**

```
function round_up (val, precision) {
    power = Math.pow (10, precision);
    poweredVal = Math.ceil (val * power);
    result = poweredVal / power;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ohk @ahmed . I understand  but it is giving wrong value in some special cases ...Thanks for Help...

Comment: Thanks @ahmed for this code ...but it  not properly working for 55.951
if third digit is greater than or equal to 5 then should be round otherwise 2 digit will show as same