# Why toFixed() in Javascript acts like that?

Tags: javascript

In this example/behaviour is something very strange.

Why does the function `toFixed` for the first two examples work and for this last one not?

```js
    //example 1
    var num = 554.956;
    var n = num.toFixed(2)
    console.log(n);
    var num2 = 554.955;
    var n2 = num2.toFixed(2)
    console.log(n2);

    //output 554.96 and 554.96

    //example 2        
    var num5 = 5.956;
    var n5 = num5.toFixed(2)
    console.log(n5);
    var num6 = 5.955;
    var n6 = num6.toFixed(2)
    console.log(n6);

    //output 5.96 and 5.96
    
    //example 3
    var num3 = 55.956;
    var n3 = num3.toFixed(2)
    console.log(n3);
    var num4 = 55.955;
    var n4 = num4.toFixed(2)
    console.log(n4);
    
    //output 55.96 and 55.95
```

Related to: [php round vs javascript toFixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802830/php-roundnum-2-and-javascipt-tofixed2-is-not-giving-right-output-for-this-v?noredirect=1#comment74645553_43802830)

EDIT: about the duplicates especially this one: [toFixed function not working properly ( please give a reason not an alternative)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008083/tofixed-function-not-working-properly-please-give-a-reason-not-an-alternative)

The answer is very good and helps me to understand the difference between x.955 and x.956, but doesn't answer why this happens only to the `55.955` in my example and not to the `5.955` or `554.955`.

Comment: What would you expect to behave differently?

Comment: Please do search in stackoverflow before posting ... checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008083/tofixed-function-not-working-properly-please-give-a-reason-not-an-alternative

Comment: the answer to last example to be `55.96` and `55.96`

Comment: this two duplicates just tell me about rounding or why is a string etc.. the best close answer is the duplicate from @BibyAugustine, but that as well is not satisfying completely my question, because in all examples I use the same decimal values ( xxx.955 and xxx.956)

Comment: You actually don't say much more than "does not work" so I'm not fully sure of what your doubt is but... It's [by design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed): *«The number is rounded if necessary»*. The rationale is that most of the times you want to minimize precision loss.

Comment: @Edwin It's not about the decimal part, it's about the whole number. Check the duplicate about floating point representation. Basically, `.554955e3`, `.55955e2` and `.5955e1` are *very* different numbers (using the same principle on decimal numbers, not binary ones)